# Can i use Google play games services for non games

Tags: google-play-games

I have one android app and I´d like to put some features with gamification.
Can I use google play games services for an app that´s not a game?
The idea is to unlock achievements as more the user uses an app and also give some prizes for the top leaderboards in the month.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible as long as you use the Classes/Objects related to Google Play Game Services like AchievementsClient, LeaderboardsClient, EventsClient, PlayersClient, etc. You can view the samples in [android-basic-samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples).

Follow the Setup Here:
[Setting Up Google Play Games Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling)